# Python gCloud billing APIs from CloudRun container instance gives 404 error

Tags: python, api, gcloud, google-cloud-run, billing

The account that is running cloudrun has been linked to the billing account, but still the cloud billing python apis throw errors. What else needs to be done in the service account ?

#1. Created json token for service account and passed into the access_bills() method

#2. The service account has role for Billing Access View

#3. Copied these methods as advised in comments from John Hanley's blog:

```
def load_private_key(json_cred):
    ''' Return the private key from the json credentials '''

    return json_cred['private_key']


def create_signed_jwt(pkey, pkey_id, email, scope):
    '''
    Create a Signed JWT from a service account Json credentials file
    This Signed JWT will later be exchanged for an Access Token
    '''

    # Google Endpoint for creating OAuth 2.0 Access Tokens from Signed-JWT
    auth_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"
    expires_in = 3600

    issued = int(time.time())
    expires = issued + expires_in   # expires_in is in seconds

    # Note: this token expires and cannot be refreshed. The token must be recreated

    # JWT Headers
    additional_headers = {
            'kid': pkey_id,
            "alg": "RS256", # Google uses SHA256withRSA
            "typ": "JWT"
    }

    # JWT Payload
    payload = {
        "iss": email,       # Issuer claim
        "sub": email,       # Issuer claim
        "aud": auth_url,    # Audience claim
        "iat": issued,      # Issued At claim
        "exp": expires,     # Expire time
        "scope": scope      # Permissions
    }

    # Encode the headers and payload and sign creating a Signed JWT (JWS)
    sig = jwt.encode(payload, pkey, algorithm="RS256", headers=additional_headers)

    return sig


def exchangeJwtForAccessToken(signed_jwt):
    '''
    This function takes a Signed JWT and exchanges it for a Google OAuth Access Token
    '''

    auth_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"

    params = {
        "grant_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
        "assertion": signed_jwt
    }

    r = requests.post(auth_url, data=params)

    if r.ok:
        return(r.json()['access_token'], '')

    return None, r.text


def access_bills(sa_json):
    cred = json.loads(sa_json)
    private_key = load_private_key(cred)
    # scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform" # this does not work, gets 404
    scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-billing.readonly"

    s_jwt = create_signed_jwt(
            private_key,
            cred['private_key_id'],
            cred['client_email'],
            scopes)

    token, err = exchangeJwtForAccessToken(s_jwt)

    if token is None:
        logger.error("Error: {}".format(err))
        exit(1)

    
    logger.info("Token response: {}".format(token))

    # the token is obtained and prints in the log

    headers = {
        "Host": "www.googleapis.com",
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

    try:
        url = "https://cloudbilling.googleapis.com/v1/billingAccounts/01C8DC-336472-E177E1" # account name is "Billing Core"
        response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
        logger.info("Response: {}".format(response))

        # logs -> app - INFO - Response: <Response [404]>

        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': 'Success'
        }
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Error")
        raise e
```

It gives 404 error as shown in the comment log after trying on that url.

Comment: Can you provide the specific error/s? Also, it would be best to [**create a minimal, reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks @RobertG I have added more details

Comment: Is your request including `Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>`? The error message indicates your request is not.

Comment: Google Cloud does not recommend passing json file as credentials, how to get that token from service account (this cloudrun assigned with) is nowhere in the gcloud documentation. Can you show me some light on this @JohnHanley ?

Comment: Search on Stack Overflow. I have written answers on how to use Python to get an OAuth Access Token with a service account. Also articles on my personal blog.

Comment: @JohnHanley I am trying to find but haven't found your answer yet. Thanks.

Comment: Okay somehow, I got the token by doing this:
 auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
    id_token = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(auth_req, "https://cloudbilling.googleapis.com")

But still getting <Response [401]> while accessing url = "https://cloudbilling.googleapis.com/v1/billingAccounts" using python requests, I have included that received token as, Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN> in header

Comment: You are using an ID Token instead of an Access Token. Here is a link to see how tokens are created from a service account: https://www.jhanley.com/blog/google-cloud-creating-oauth-access-tokens-for-rest-api-calls/

Comment: But google does not recommend creating a json key for a service account, what is the best practice here ?

Comment: @JohnHanley The json token is obtained following exactly your blog, but when tried to access cloud billing api, https://cloudbilling.googleapis.com/v1/billingAccounts, it gets 404 Not Found error. Any lights on this issue ?

Comment: Update your question with the new code and error messages. 404 means not found. Double check the URI

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley I have updated the question, code and error log above

Comment: 1) Add the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` Scopes are separated by a space character. Do not try to control permissions via scopes. Let IAM do that for you, 2) I do not recognize the REST API: `/v1/billingAccounts/Billing%20Core`. Do you have a link for that API's documentation?

Comment: Added scopes separated by spaces and re-ran, and also corrected the api 
/v1/billingAccounts/01C8DC-336472-E177E1, but still got 404.
https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/reference/rest/v1/billingAccounts/get

Comment: All scopes as in the doc:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-billing https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-billing.readonly

But still the same, 404

Comment: @JohnHanley any insights if you kind of know why this is not working ?

Comment: The billing details I am trying to extract is from a linked billing account to this current project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found that the only way it works as of now is via big query export from billing account, sort out dataViewer permission and run the corresponding sql from python application, it works.